Calculate noise figure for LNA + SAW + RTLSDR
I'm trying to optimize the SNR of low-power RF pulses (from wildlife telemetry tags @166Mhz, unmodulated, a few DBs above noise floor) as they go into an RTLSDR. I have a number of questions about how to calculate the effects of adding an LNA and SAW filter.
Sample system:

PSA4-5043+ LNA https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/PSA4-5043+.pdf
TA0168A SAW filter https://www.taisaw.com/assets/PDF/TA0168A%20_Rev.3.0_.pdf
E4000 tuner https://www.nooelec.com/files/e4000datasheet.pdf

According to the datasheets the NF of the LNA is around 0.7dB, the gain around 23dB, and the tuner's NF is around 4.5dB. The SAW filter datasheet doesn't list a noise figure but the insertion loss is the insertion loss is 6dB.
I'm familiar with Friis' formula for multi-stage amplifiers but how does the SAW filter factor in?

Treat the SAW filter as an attenuator stage with -6dB gain and 6dB noise figure and the receiver as a stage with 0dB gain and 4.5dB noise figure.

Screenshot is from Ladpac2008, an older package of design tools mainly for ham radio. Available here: http://w7zoi.net/emerrata.html
